# How do golden and jade tools stack?

Tags: make-more

In the most recent update of Make More (v1.2), jade tools are added,giving you a 3x bonus. There were already golden tools available, that gave a 2x bonus. Are they stacked, and if yes, how?

[image: screenshot of jade tools]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The multipliers wont stack. If you're working with jade tools, you're not working with golden tools.

If you work with default tools you get 1x profit.

If you work with golden tools you get 2x profit.

If you work with jade tools you get 3x profit.

You can buy Jade tools only if you have already golden tools.